# Storing and Updating Lat Long Values in the Database in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

I am Using Google Maps iOS SDK in my application. I Write the Below Code for Getting Latitude and Longitude of particular Place if the user Long Press at a Location get the Address of the Lat Longs and store them in an array and load that array into UITableView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
 UIScrollView  *scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];

 [self.view addSubview:scroll];
 scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:17.3600
                                                        longitude:78.4760 zoom:9 ];
 map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,390) camera:camera];
 [scroll addSubview:map];
 self->map.delegate = self;

 tab = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 405, self.view.bounds.size.width, 250) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 [scroll addSubview:tab];

 tab.delegate = self;
 tab.dataSource = self;
 markerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 addressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapViewdidLongPressAtCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
 {
  if([markerArray count]>=5)
  {
    UIAlertView *al = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"U Have Already Added 5 Favourite Locations" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [al show];
  }
  else
  {
   NSLog(@"%f",coordinate.latitude);
   NSLog(@"%f",coordinate.longitude);

   l1 = coordinate.latitude;
   l2 = coordinate.longitude;

   GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
   marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
   marker.appearAnimation = YES;
   marker.map = mapView;
   [markerArray addObject:marker];
   [self location];
   }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [addressArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if(!cell)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc ]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }
 cell.textLabel.text = [addressArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
}
```

Now My Task is i Want to store those Lat Longs Locally after the user clicks on the Submit button. and also if the user wants to update the points i want to Update (Add/Delete) those points from the database and marker related to that Lat longs and save them again in the Database.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: I guess in the first instance you need to decide what type of data persistence you wish to use: Core Data, SQLite, Plist…, as it sounds as if you haven't thought of this yet?

Comment: @Nick I Want to Store them Using Core Data.

Comment: Have you looked into Core Data then?

Comment: Ya I know Core Data. My Problem is First time i am loading array data into table if i update that table i was unable to store that updated data to database.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at something like:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html or
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Comment: The code you have supplied does not show any form of data persistence?

Comment: Right now i am doing that one.

Comment: @Nick What my Task is Store 5 Lat Langs Locally and retrieve after Login and show markers on the Map and Update those Lat Langs(Add/Delete) again store them in My Application. For this one what i have to Use? Databse or any other method for this.

Comment: You could use core data, however if this is the only data persistence you need to do in the app, then maybe user defaults would be best. Have you used them before?

Comment: Yes I am Having Small idea about NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Nick also i want to show Address related to Those Lat langs in a Table thats My Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store your array of 5 lat/long values you would do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:markeyArray forKey:YOUR_KEY];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

then when you wish to retrieve them:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:YOUR_KEY];
```

as for getting the address from the coordinates, you should look into reverse geocoding.